# How should I optimize/structure my database for collecting webshop price development?

Tags: php, mysql, database, optimization

I have a small personal project, which is supposed to collect data from different webshops. What I basically do, is run a cron script every night. This script uses the Simple HTML DOM Parser for PHP to fetch prices for products in selected product groups.

As of now, my database consists of three tables:
- `stores` Name, URL etc for each webshop
- `products` URL, product names etc for each product
- `prices` Prices for every day each product

**My question** is the `prices` table. Every time the cron script runs, it saves new entries with price data for each product (300+), even if the products price is unchanged. I know I can prevent saving unnecessary data with a check to see wether the price is changed or not. But then again a product can be taken out of stock, leaving me no information of when it went out of stock (which it would if I saved the price each day). How would you guys do this more effective? The cron script would potentially take a long time to execute because of the DOM parsing, and I want to be sure everything is parsed and added to database as expected.

Comment: i would keep it the way you're doing it, data is good, i think the value of having the lifetime price changes for products is worth storing the prices every day even if they dont change, i think you have to carefully decide what `unecessary data` means to you.

Comment: That's very true. Although, if I only save the adjustments in price, I will still know that the price is valid until the next adjustment. The database would be clogged up by thousands of entries with the same information otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could keep track of each DOM you parsed, and store a checksum of it to see if it has changed when you load it again the next night. If the checksum is the same, you'll know you need no parsing and no updating because nothing will have changed.

Comment: But the DOM would almost always change, because of different content on the pages. A product group view would have different headers for campaigns etc, so using checksum would be worthless. +1 for the idea though!